# Errors inside comments..?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error

I'm getting weird errors including errors inside comments (see screenshot).

Visual Studio 2010

Targeting .NET 4

Addons:

- PInvoke.net
- PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010
- Productivity Power Tools
- SQL Server Compact Toolbox
- Visual Assist X

[image: Errors in comments. aka getting my opinion wrong]

Comment: Well, the editor thinks you have an error in the string you assign to `cb.DataSource` as well... It should still build fine though.

Comment: @Yuck I mouse over them and no error pops up. It doesn't build and that's the problem.

Comment: And to whoever thumbs downed this question, at least have the intelligence to leave a reason or it doesn't help the community improve their questions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'll post the errors it's giving at build after meetings and lunch. The errors like assigning "masterkey" string are what's befuddling me.  #ProductivityMeetings

Comment: @Yuck Actually, paths were the problem for the errors inside the comments. Make that an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Apparently, `connection` and `Pre1p14p2Adp` and `MakeAdapter(connection)` aren't correct either. Maybe those are the reason why your project is not building?

Comment: @Nolonar You're right with the way I have it commented in the screenshot. I just did that to show the error stayed even when commented out. When uncommented, it keeps other errors. I'll work at it some more then post as a new question since what I asked has technically been solved. (path error in comment due to add-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which add-ons you're using. Sometimes they attempt to verify paths (even in comments). Although I haven't seen this prevent a build before I'm sure it's possible that is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, there are two types of errors:

1. **Syntax errors** (e.g. `connection` underlined - probably because the declaration is commented out).
2. **Grammar errors** (e.g. "Dropbox" in comments).
   Nowadays, most IDEs check your documentation comments for typos, using a dictionary (thesaurus). If a word is not in the dictionary, it is underlined. Of course, the grammar checking often can't recognize a path and it just considers every path component a word.